# How can I still get the value when join fails sperately?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this, and everytime If anything of first_name, last_name, url doesn't exist it doesn't return anything.

what I'm trying to do is, even If it doesn't have a single value(let's say `url`) I still want to get first_name and last_name. How can I make it happen?

```
SELECT a.first_name, a.last_name, b.url 
  FROM USER AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN FILE_ATTACH_INFO b ON a.uid = b.user_id
```

Comment: @JRLambert is there a difference?

Comment: your query looks alright. even if url is null it would still display firstname and lastname plus null URL

Comment: I suspect your query is more complicated.  `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` are the same thing.

Comment: there is more than meets the eye

Comment: Do you want to return url even if user does not exist?